# Get the offset for the selected text after html tag

Tags: javascript, offset

Can someone please suggest me how to get the selection offset of the text after `html` tag? I need the actual offset with respect to the start of the text in `div`.

```
<div>
  Sentence to select the <i>text and highlight</i> it accordingly
</div>
```

If I highlight the text in the `div`, for example, "*text and highlight*," using the JavaScript code

```
window.getSelection().baseOffset
```

I get offset as 0 instead of 24. Is there a way that I can get the actual offset, i.e. 24?

Comment: baseOffset? Never heard before. Maybe you could use [focusOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/focusOffset)?

Comment: You need to provide more code. Include the event in which you are firing the `getSelection()`

Comment: its just a button click. Once the selection is done, click on the button which contains the window.getSelection().baseOffset code